# How can I use google web fonts with phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, webfonts

I'm using phantomjs version 1.9.7 which I believe is supposed to support web fonts. I have inserted the font with google web fonts however it is just displaying my fallback font when I automate a screengrab. The webfont is displaying fine in all my browsers. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Am adding this to my css: @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

Comment: I just tried [Bootstrap Fonts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) with phantomjs version 1.9.7 on Windows and the capture worked. Maybe you can try to include it the same way, because there are multiple fallbacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have struggled with this issue for several hours. Well, there is a simple reason for this controversy: **user-agent**!

Some services such as Google Fonts are returning different CSS content based on user-agent. When you call a webpage which includes Google Fonts **with** default PhantomJs user-agent, Google would return TTF version which is supported in PhantomJs.

However, if you set a **custom user agent** (Chrome, FF, etc.), Google Fonts would return `.woff2` version. `.woff2` is not supported in PhantomJs 2.x. Obviously, fonts are not going to be loaded.

So, for users who are testing PhantomJs without setting a generic user-agent, Google Fonts is working. If they set for example Google Chrome user-agent, it does not work.

So, you have two options:

1. Avoid setting a custom user-agent if it is possible.
2. Avoid using dumb-smart font providers like Google Fonts which does not outputting all font versions in CSS and let the browser decide what it needs.

Comment: I was able to verify this even in PhantomJS 2.1.1. The default UA of `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 (development) Safari/534.34` (with 'Chrome' absent) seems to work as you described above. Nice catch.

Comment: As for now (2017) situation became opposite: Google Fonts returns `.woff2` fonts for default UA `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1`. So to fix issue none-standard User-Agent should be set, like just `PhantomJS/2.1.1` for example.

Comment: @shytikov This is exactly what is mentioned in the answer. So nothing is changed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your belief is wrong :-)
The 1.9.x series of Phantom is still based on the old WebKit code, which people have been reporting web font problems with all along.

The good news is that a technical preview of Phantom 2.0 is apparently about to be released; https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/PhantomJS-2 is intended to be the best place to follow status. And, from memory, someone reported success with web fonts using it (but I may be wrong on that as a quick search of the mailing list archives didn't turn up a definitive message saying web fonts work... but they definitely *should*).

BTW, [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) is an almost drop-in replacement, based on Firefox's Gecko engine, and does support web fonts (though some problems in corner cases, IIRC).

Comment: "I believe..." an example or even a link to something leading you to believe this would be helpful. There is a closed issue here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10592. It continues to be a troubling problem, however. An example of it working would be the most helpful.

Comment: @st.derrick Web fonts not being supported in the Phantom 1.x series is something I had seen mentioned on the phantom mailing list. (The corner case problems with web fonts in SlimerJS were mentioned on the slimer mailing list.)

Comment: @st.derrick Just read through that bug issue. Sounds about how I remembered it - a big mess!  Some people still saying it is not working reliably even with PhantomJS 2.0 - it sounds like there may be some complicated dependencies on Ubuntu packages?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with PhantomJS 2.1.1.
In my case I was working under a proxy that was blocking PhantomJS from loading the font from Google. After connecting to an open network it rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all fixes listed here to no avail, but here is a work around. Either option resolved this for me.

**First Option:**
Install the missing web fonts on the local computer that is running PhantomJS. Most web font providers including Google allow you to easily download the fonts for local install. No change needed at the target URL.

**Second:**
I sites I have control over, I was able to resolve by splitting up the link tags.

**Change This from:**

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**To:**

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I know this is not an ideal solution but either one works, It depends on if you can modify the target URL.