# phantomjs + web fonts + font loader

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, webfonts, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

I'm running [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) within a `node.js` environment, and it's going well.  At the moment I'm just using local fonts, but want to get [google web fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) working with phantomjs.

There are various conflicting and confusing reports out there about whether and how web fonts can be made to work with `phantomjs`.  There are articles like [this](http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html) that contain outdated information with dead links.  And posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408457/4070848) that suggest that **phantomjs 2.0** will or can support web fonts, others saying that it doesn't but **2.0.1** will.  In [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10592) post there is a suggestion that webfonts do work in **2.0**.

I've tried lots of options, including with **phantomjs 2.0** and [2.0.1](https://github.com/gitromand/phantomjs/releases/tag/2.0.1) binaries, but can't get it working.  It may be that I'm loading the web fonts in my js using the [web font loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) using something along the following:

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    },
    loading: function() { console.log('loading'); },
    active: function() {
        console.log('active');
        // hooray!  can do stuff...
    },
    inactive: function() { console.log('inactive'); },
    fontloading: function(familyName, fvd) { console.log('fontloading', familyName, fvd); },
    fontactive: function(familyName, fvd) { console.log('fontactive', familyName, fvd); },
    fontinactive: function(familyName, fvd) { console.log('fontinactive', familyName, fvd); }
});
```

But I'm always reaching the `inactive` branch, so the font load is never successful... even though the same code works fine in a browser (reaching the `active` branch.

In the [font loader docs](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#browser-support), it says:

> If Web Font Loader determines that the current browser does not support `@font-face`, the `inactive` event will be triggered.

My suspicion is that web font loader is indeed determining that the browser (phantomjs) does not support this, hence always reaching `inactive`.

Anyone got phantomjs + web fonts + web font loader working?

Answer (score 4):

What is the UA you are using? I think Web Font Loader uses UA to detect the support. Try a UA of Chrome 46 and then see if it works.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36';
```

Comment: Sadly, no difference :-(  Tried this with phantomjs 1.9.8, 2.0.0 and 2.0.1... each time it only reaches the `inactive` branch

Comment: I did just try with phantomjs@1.9.19, changing the userAgent. Logs: `loading`, `active`..

Comment: Do you have any code snippets to share @cviejo?  I still can't get it to the `active` branch...

Comment: Ouch, sorry, forgot! Will post today

Answer (score 2):

Not to be marked as correct, just expanding on the above answer. Since all phantomjs wrappers (like [phridge](https://github.com/peerigon/phridge) and [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node)) basically spawn a new phantomjs process, the result should be the same when run from a nodejs context.

**phatomjs-webfonts.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PhantomJS WebFontsTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
        },
        loading:  function(){ console.log('WebFonts loading'); },
        active:   function(){ console.log('WebFonts active'); },
        inactive: function(){ console.log('WebFonts inactive'); }
    });
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**phantomjs-webfonts.js:**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36';

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('Console: ' + msg);
};

page.open('http://<server-address>/phantomjs-webfonts.html', function(status) {
  console.log("Loading status: " + status);
});
```

**Command:**

```
phantomjs phantomjs-webfonts.js
```

**Output**:

```
Console: WebFonts loading
Console: WebFonts active
Loading status: success
```

Comment: What version of phantomjs?  `$ phantomjs -v`

Comment: I didn't know there was even a 1.9.19?  See http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html  Or are you referring to the phantomjs npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs which has a version of 1.9.19 at present?

Comment: Looks like it, indeed. I did my tests on my home machine, will post the right version info tonight then.